# more regex: need to setup some redirects to handle duplicate URL reports by big brother (goog)

Tags: php, regex

the mighty Google apparently makes up its own URLS now to try to locate pages. We have spent allot of time making sure our URL navigation is spot on, but "dont be evil" is being evil and claiming that allot of our pages are duplicates.....

eg:

/properties/2531/812/

/properties/2531/812/bisto-prego-Monmouth-Monmouthshire-United Kingdom/

/properties/2531/812/bisto-prego-monmouth-monmouthshire-united-kingdom/

/properties/2531/812/bisto-prego-monmouth-monmouthshire-united-kingdom

you guessed it, the page is actually found at /properties/2531/812/, the rest is simply there for SEO effort.

So because google is trying it on, we are now seeing loads of duplicate content reports in our webmaster tools.

Easy enough to handle, we will just make our index.php script allot stricter and run a 303 redirect if the url is not as well formed as we would like. That should sort the sheriff out!

```
    $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];                                 // check the URL to make sure it is well formed

if(!preg_match("/\?/",$uri))                                        // some pages include a ? and query string, so we will ignore those
{

    if(!regex needed to check for presence of trailing slash)                                                   // now check for trailing slash
    {
        $uri = $uri."/";                                        // add trailing slash
        header("Location: http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]/$uri");    // redirect and set header 303          
        exit;                                                   

    }
}
```

We can easiliy detect if the seo part of the URI is present, but still having trouble detecting the ? and if there is a trailing slash....
So regex question: first off, how to detect presence of ?query=string etc in the url, and secondly how to detect if a trailing slash is present...

Comment: Don't use `HTTP_HOST`. [It's evil](http://perfect-co.de/2011/02/why-http_host-is-evil/).

Comment: should note that it is important to only apply redirect on pages that do not contain any query string data, or contain the trailing slash. Otherwise we will be redirecting all pages in an infinite loop. for that reason we have disounted trim()

Comment: I don't understand how any of this is google's fault. I don't know who does SEO for your site but if they: 1. Suggest you use the first link with just a bunch of numbers instead of the 4th link which is actually descriptive and 2. Proposed you leave up multiple pages with the same content without `rel="canonical"` or 301 redirects for SEO purposes, which by the way actually hurts each of your pages rankings because instead of consolidating search results to get a high rank for those keywords it's splitting inbound links' pagerank, I high recommend finding someone else. This is google helping u

Comment: I ran out of characters, but I also wanted to mention be very very careful around 303 redirects. Unless the page you're 303 redirecting to is already number 1 very securely for your phrases AND the 303 redirect page ranks highly as well so you get 2 results to your site on first page google, it's better to avoid it and 301.

Comment: @inTide I just read your comments after posting my answer, I totally agree.

Comment: @inTide the reasons we think google is at fault here is that they are not following our URLs, surely googlebot will only follow URLs that it finds elsewhere? We are using the 301 to tidy up a mess that has been created by googles ability to apparently interpret URLS however it sees fit. We want to tie down all these erroneous pages and instead only offer the page using the correct URL scheme, which as you pointed out is descriptive. Oh, quite right, 301 is better than 303, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Nick I don't understand what you mean when you say it's googlebot's fault. Unless you tell googlebot specifically not to crawl those pages, it will (eventually) find them. It's the only way to index new pages with no inbound links, it won't visit very often because of low/no inbound links, but it'll still visit if you don't tell it not to visit and/or store into cache. As for how they do that, they won't tell us all the details :| It didn't make those URLs on your site, those URLs exist because for some reason the CMS you use didn't clean it up so you have to.

Comment: @inTide I guess its apparent then that they are assuming that there might be content within the directory tree in the URL. Interesting. Also is interesting to note that googlebot seems to also have a go at injection, based on some of the URLs we see in our bespoke in house stats. You would be amazed what you see when not relying soley on GA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to see if any query params are present. It'll be empty if none are there.

Use `'/$'` to check for trailing slash

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry if I misunderstand something, but would not it be easier to specify your `canonical` URL? Google understands it quite well.

```
 <link rel="canonical" href="http://x.com//properties/2531/812/bisto-prego-Monmouth-Monmouthshire-United Kingdom/" />
```

[Read more on the Google Webmaster Central Blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)

Comment: We are indeed also adding the cononical URL too, but we want to tidy up the url parsing too to make the site allot tidier